# is there anyway to know if your supposedly fully dedicated server is really a virtually resource-shared machine?

Tags: performance, central-processing-unit, benchmark

sometimes I feel my server not responding as smoothly as I would expect (i have a Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU 2.80GHz Quad Core), given that for example, the 'top' commands reports a low load < 0.5, CPU are almost completely idle ...

I maybe have internet connectivity issues, so I don't really know if it's me or if it's the server itself.

Is there anykind of benchmarking script (or something analogous) I could run and see the actual performance of the server ?

Comment: drive there and ask to take a look?

Answer (score 7):

The `virt-what` script will identify many different types of hypervisors and container technologies. It's pre-packaged for most major Linux distributions (e.g. `apt-get install virt-what` or `yum install virt-what`) and its output is suitable for use in shell scripts. It correctly performs its detection from inside the virtual guest.

> Current types of virtualization detected:
>
> - hyperv       Microsoft Hyper-V
> - kvm          Linux Kernel Virtual Machine (KVM)
> - lxc          Linux Containers
> - openvz       OpenVZ or Virtuozzo
> - powervm_lx86 IBM PowerVM Lx86 Linux/x86 emulator
> - qemu         QEMU (unaccelerated)
> - uml          User-Mode Linux (UML)
> - virtage      Hitachi Virtualization Manager (HVM) Virtage LPAR
> - virtualbox   VirtualBox
> - virtualpc    Microsoft VirtualPC
> - vmware       VMware
> - xen          Xen
> - xen-dom0     Xen dom0 (privileged domain)
> - xen-domU     Xen domU (paravirtualized guest domain)
> - xen-hvm      Xen guest fully virtualized (HVM)

The Puppet tool `facter` uses `virt-what` internally to determine the type of virtualization in use, so if you are using Puppet, you already have this installed.

Comment: This is a wonderful solution... that doesn't work on anything that isn't Linux (or doesn't have a linux-like `/proc`). All the world is not a Linux box...

Comment: @voretaq7 It only uses `/proc` to detect Linux containers and UML; it uses `dmidecode` and calling Intel's CPUID instruction from assembly for everything else. It should be portable to BSD with minimal modification.

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, it is possible to look for *tell-tale* signs of virtualisation depending on the type of hypervisor used. You can typically start by looking in `/proc/cpuinfo` for the CPU type. Some hypervisors report *fake* CPU types such as "QEMU Virtual CPU". If it is running VZ, you can find `/proc/user_beancounters` that report resource usage. With Xen, you will find a `/proc/xen` directory.

So, it is possible to guess if you are running under some sort of virtualisation.

Comment: so does this mean that /proc/cpuinfo never lies abour what CPU you have ?

Comment: No! I cat /proc/cpuinfo on my vmware virutal machine and cpu is Genuine Intel Xeon...

Comment: @siran - it's possible to lie but like I said, that's just a place to start, and it is a process of elimination.

@lg - you can check /proc/vmware to know that it is running vmware.

Answer (score 3):

If you can run perl scripts (depending on your OS), there's one called [`imvirt`](http://micky.ibh.net/~liske/imvirt.html) which can detect quite a few based on various system info (`/proc/cpuinfo`, `dmidecode`, etc.) - it sounds like you're on ubuntu, so there are packages for Jaunty, Karmic and Lucid, or you can grab it from [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imvirt/files/).

Answer (score 1):

There are things that were looked at by the antivirus companies for detecting blue pill virus variants.

Basically it's extremely hard for a VM to match the real time clock with the CPU counters.  If you have access to install a driver, you should be able to put the system into no interrupts and watch the counters.  If you have a virtualised system then your clock will drift in chunks when the VM is switched out by the hypervisor (which is supposedly impossible based on the interrupt bit).

Comment: this sound interesting... how can this be done in a Ubuntu Linux box ?

Comment: As I said, write a driver, disable interrupts in your driver, then create a real time loop that is watching the RTC on the system.  If it ever drifts by more than the real time cycles that you should have allocated then you are in a VM.  Note that you couldn't wait too long in your driver otherwise you'll probably break some hardware that has to process interrupts to work.

Answer (score 0):

Look for [steal cpu cycles](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2013/07/25/understanding-cpu-steal-time-when-should-you-be-worried).  You can get this in top for example.  "If your VM displays a high %st in top (steal time), this means CPU cycles are being taken away from your VM to serve other purposes."