# Is there a way to determine which vps software that my vps is using?

Tags: vps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there anyway to know if your supposedly fully dedicated server is really a virtually resource-shared machine ?](https://serverfault.com/questions/149877/is-there-anyway-to-know-if-your-supposedly-fully-dedicated-server-is-really-a-vir)

I am wondering is there a way that I can determine which VPS software(Virtuozzo, Xen or OpenVZ) is used to implement the VPS which I am using.

Answer (score 1):

On my box:

```
# dmesg | grep -i xen
Xen: 0000000000000000 - 0000000020800000 (usable)
Kernel command line: root=/dev/xvda xencons=tty console=tty1 console=hvc0 nosep nodevfs ramdisk_size=32768 ip_conntrack.hashsize=8192 nf_conntrack.hashsize=8192 ro 
Xen reported: 2500.088 MHz processor.
xen_mem: Initialising balloon driver.
Xen virtual console successfully installed as tty1
xen-vbd: registered block device major 202
XENBUS: Device with no driver: device/console/0
```

There are probably some similar traces of the virtualization solution you are using whichever it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always Xen, KVM, or ESX. You can usually look through the dmesg or hardware and figure it out pretty quick. Asking your hosting provider usually gets the answer too...

Comment: Thanks, can you post the details about how to use dmesg to figure it out? The hosting provider simply doesn't offer me this information for no reasons:(.

Comment: @DavidLiu, Have you contacted customer support, or are you just going off their website? Usually companies don't advertise which technology they're using (as it usually doesn't matter) but will tell you if you call.